# Projectile motion in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have followed a couple for tutorials and tried coming  up with script that can make my object follow the trajectory but unfortunately none of my attempts worked. I understand the basic physics and math of projectile motion but not able to program.

Here is the situation:

A is a fixed object at some height above the ground and throws the object that has to follow the projectile motion and B is moving towards A(to left) with constant speed in linear motion.I just want the game object from A to follow the projectile motion on click of a button. I have done tons of attempts on my own but it did not work.

Comment: -1 for "It did not work". In exactly what way did it "not work"? Exactly what did you try?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in improving your post.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I tried a couple of methods--> Simplest i tried was using AddForce in upward direction in addition  to Gravity . Besides that I tried calculating the launching angle for the object to hit target destination but none of them worked.

Comment: So, try showing us what you tried, and show us what you mean by "it didn't work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's be more specific. The projectile is launched from point A and needs to hit B, who is moving horizontally with constant speed in 2D.

This is the position of the projectile, over time:

```
P.x = A0.x + VP0.x * t
P.y = A0.y + VP0.y * t - g/2 * t^2
```

And this is the position of B, over time:

```
B.x = B0.x + VB0.x * t
B.y = B0.y
```

Where A0 is the position of A, at time 0; B0 is the position of B, at time 0; VB0 is the velocity of B (constant and horizontal only) and VP0 is the velocity with which we're going to launch the projectile. If we constrain the system by tuning the value of 't' (the time it takes for the projectile to hit B), then we need to resolve VP0. We do this by saying that at collision time, P and B will be equal:

```
A0.x + VP0.x * t = B0.x + VB0.x * t
A0.y + VP0.y * t - g/2 * t^2 = B0.y
```

Resolving VP0:

```
VP0.x = (B0.x - A0.x)/t + VB0.x
VP0.y = (B0.y - A0.y)/t + g/2 * t
```

Now that we have the velocity for the projectile, simulating it can be done in a straightforward way using the formula above:

```
// calculate velocity when firing projectile
launchVelocity.x = (b.x - a.x) / desired_time + velocity_b.x;
launchVelocity.y = (b.y - a.x) / desired_time + gravity / 2 * desired_time;

// then for each frame, update position
elapsedTime += dt;
projectile.x = a.x + launchVelocity.x * elapsedTime;
projectile.y = a.y + (launchVelocity.y - gravity / 2 * elapsedTime) * elapsedTime;
```

One note is that if B is moving towards A, velocity_b can be negative.

Answer (score -1):

Basically i needed to instantiate at the time of shooting(and hence in the source script) rather than in the projectile script

This helped:
[Projectile motion](http://lexiconhub.tk/index/game-programming/projectile-motion-unity-3d/#.U-KEp_mSzws)